# Launch not executing when called inside a coroutinescope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-snackbar, coroutinescope

I'm calling launch inside a coroutinescope but it does not execute. Snackbar action listener is executing but the launch block is not executing for some reason.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    val scope = this
    val mn = snackbarManager(R.id.root)
    Snackbar
        .make(mn.container, R.string.recpt_deleted, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction(R.string.undo) {
            scope.launch { // not executing
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Committing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d("COMMIT", "calling commit")
            }
        }
        .show()
}
```

Comment: I think the answer of @Sergio is perfect. Just  wanted to mention that it is easier to make this mistake if not writing scope.launch but simply launch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `scope` you are using in Snackbar action listener is not the same scope you use to call the first `launch` function. To tackle the problem you can make a reference to the main `CoroutineScope`:

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
scope.launch {
    // ...
    // in action listener:
    scope.launch { /*...*/ }
}
```

Or use another `CoroutineScope` in Snackbar action listener, for example, `lifecycleScope` property:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Committing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    Log.d("COMMIT", "calling commit")
}
```

But in my opinion your code is a little bit mess. I think you should reconsider your approach and don't use the `CoroutineScope` to show the `Snackbar`.

UPDATE:

When you initialize `scope` variable in the first coroutine `val scope = this`, this `scope` becomes **COMPLETED** when the outer coroutine is finished. When you launch inner coroutine in `Snackbar` action listener the `scope` already has **COMPLETED** state. We can't launch a coroutine using `CoroutineScope` with **COMPLETED** state.

Comment: My understanding is that launch should always execute regardless of which scope one is using. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Perfect answer. I think the developers of Kotlin should consider a terminating exception in this case.

Comment: It can happen also when allegedly following coroutines rules. The code in the question is of a Snackbar action, so it is clear that it is executed later from message queue. But my code was using only coroutines (though to implement a callback mechanism). Still it happened. That was because Dispatchers.Main is not just keeping using the main thread, but it dispatches to message queue. To execute in place, use Dispatchers.Main.immediate (does not help with the question code). https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/launching-a-kotlin-coroutine-for-immediate-execution-on-the-main-thread-8555e701163b

Answer (score 1):

For the second `scope` `launch` you should use `Dispatchers.Main` because of :

**`Main` `coroutine` `dispatcher` that is confined to the Main thread operating with UI objects. Usually such `dispatchers` are single-threaded.**

**FIRST WAY :**

Then you should change your code to this :

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    Snackbar.make(requireView(),"milad", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("clickMe"){
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Committing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d("COMMIT", "calling commit")
            }
        }.show()
}
```

---

**UPDATE :**

**SECOND WAY:**

```
   val coro= CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    coro.launch {
        Snackbar.make(requireView(),"milad", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("clickMe"){
                coro.launch {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Committing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("COMMIT", "calling commit")
                }
            }.show()
    }
```

Comment: The first `CoroutineScope` also use `Dispatchers.Main`, so that is not the problem.

Comment: No it does not use `Dispatchers.Main` , if it use this it worked fine , by update my answer it will use `Dispatchers.Main` too again in second scope.

Comment: @miladsalimi shouldn’t launch block be executed regardless of which scope it’s been used?